# GeoPandas clip returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Tags: python, geopandas, clip

I am trying to go through a CSV of points in lat/long, find the distance between them, buffer them by that distance, then take the overlap and use that overlap to clip a multiline. The clip protion is causing me some trouble; when I use myline.intersection(mypoly) I get a table with no geometry. When I use geopandas.clip(myline, mypoly) I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'. The inputs can either be geoDataFrames or GeoSeries, I tried both.

```
import os, pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd
from datetime import datetime

## inputs
bwes = r"CSVOfPoints.csv"
tracks = r"GeoPackageOfLines.gpkg"
outputdir =r"OutDir"

## variables
skippedList = [['BWEID', 'Error']] #Captures all the failed attempts

bweIDList =[]
errorList = []

## defined functions
def mdist(mdist1): #Returns the distance of 2 points in a cartesian grid (Make sure the input points are in a projected CRS, result will be base units of in CRS)
    shift_pt = mdist1.shift()
    return mdist1.distance(shift_pt)[1]

def bwebuffer(bwebuffer1): #Returns the buffer area between 2 input points. The input points here are the start and end locations (use a projected CRS)
    polys = bwebuffer1.buffer(mdist(bwebuffer1))
    return gpd.GeoSeries(polys.iloc[0].intersection(polys.iloc[1]))

## Loading dataframes
bwedf = pd.read_csv(bwes, usecols=['id', 'tomb_MMSI', 'MPDate', 'exchangestart_location_lat', 'exchangestart_location_long', 'exchangeend_location_lat', 'exchangeend_location_long'])
print('Checking input data...')

bwedfnulls = bwedf[bwedf.isnull().any(axis=1)]

if bwedfnulls.empty:
    print('No missing data...')
else:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log')):
        bwedfnulls.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir,'Error Log','nulls.csv'))
        print('Missing data found printing error log...')
    else:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log'))
        bwedfnulls.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log', 'nulls.csv'))
        print('Missing data found printing error log...')

bwedf = bwedf.dropna()
bwedfbadloc = bwedf[(bwedf.exchangestart_location_lat == bwedf.exchangeend_location_lat) & (bwedf.exchangestart_location_long == bwedf.exchangeend_location_long)]
if bwedfbadloc.empty:
    print('No bad locations found...')
else:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log')):
        bwedfbadloc.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir,'Error Log','badlocation.csv'))
        print('Bad locations found printing error log...')
    else:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log'))
        bwedfbadloc.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log', 'badlocation.csv'))
        print('Bad locations found printing error log...')
print('Input data cleared for processing...')

bwedf = bwedf[~((bwedf.exchangestart_location_lat == bwedf.exchangeend_location_lat) & (bwedf.exchangestart_location_long == bwedf.exchangeend_location_long))]
tracksgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.read_file(tracks, layer = 'TestLines'), geometry='geometry', crs=4326)

## transforming date fields to datetime objects
bwedf['MPDate'] = bwedf['MPDate'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
bwedf['tomb_MMSI'] = pd.to_numeric(bwedf['tomb_MMSI'])
tracksgdf['TrackStartTime'] = tracksgdf['TrackStartTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
tracksgdf['TrackEndTime'] = tracksgdf['TrackEndTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
tracksgdf['MMSI'] = pd.to_numeric(tracksgdf['MMSI'])

for index, row in bwedf.iterrows():
    datamask = (tracksgdf['MMSI'] == row.tomb_MMSI) & (tracksgdf['TrackStartTime'] <= row.MPDate) & (tracksgdf['TrackEndTime'] >= row.MPDate)
    ctrackgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tracksgdf[datamask], geometry='geometry', crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
    if ctrackgdf.empty == True:
        bweIDList.append(row.id)
        errorList.append('No matching track')
    else:
        startptdf = pd.DataFrame({'id': row.id, 'MMSI': row.tomb_MMSI, 'date': row.MPDate,'latitude': row.exchangestart_location_lat, 'longitude': row.exchangestart_location_long}, index=[0])  # Creates a matching dataframe for the start points, setting unix time to 0
        endptdf = pd.DataFrame({'id': row.id, 'MMSI': row.tomb_MMSI, 'date': row.MPDate,'latitude': row.exchangeend_location_lat, 'longitude': row.exchangeend_location_long}, index=[0])  # Creates a matching dataframe for the end points setting unix time to 9999999999
        ptsgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([startptdf, endptdf], ignore_index=True), geometry=gpd.array.points_from_xy(pd.concat([startptdf, endptdf], ignore_index=True).longitude, pd.concat([startptdf, endptdf], ignore_index=True).latitude), crs = 4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
        clip = bwebuffer(ptsgdf)
        bwe_event = gpd.clip(ctrackgdf, clip)
        os.chdir(outputdir)
        ctrackgdf('esri:102001').to_file('Output.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(row.id))
        clip.to_file('Output.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(row.id)+'clip')
        ptsgdf.to_file('Output.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(row.id) + 'pts')
        bwe_event.to_file('Output.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(row.id) + 'event')

errorLog = {'BWEID':bweIDList, 'Error':errorList}
errordf = pd.DataFrame(errorLog)

if errordf.empty:
    pass
else:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log')):
        errordf.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir,'Error Log','processing errors.csv'))
    else:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log'))
        errordf.to_csv(os.path.join(outputdir, 'Error Log', 'processing errors.csv'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "...PycharmProjects/BWE/BWE_V3_SMTP.py", line 76, in 
bwe_event = gpd.clip(ctrackgdf, clip)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\clip.py", line 183, in clip
line_gdf = _clip_line_poly(gdf[line_idx], poly)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\clip.py", line 74, in _clip_line_poly
sidx = list(spatial_index.intersection(bbox))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently rtree wasn't installed. My clip worked after installing rtree.